# Why _PROTOTYPE is used header files

Tags: c

Why do we use _PROTOTYPE e.g. _PROTOTYPE( void *memset, (void *_s, int _c, size_t _n) I saw it in [MINIX3 source code](http://www.minix3.org/doc/AppendixB.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because as the header block says, they didn't know if an ANSI compiler or K&R was going to be used, and this marco allows them to keep the parameters in an ANSI build, and throw them away in a K&R build.

```
00033   /* Keep everything for ANSI prototypes. */
00034   #define _PROTOTYPE(function, params)    function params
```

verse

```
00045   /* Throw away the parameters for K&R prototypes. */
00046   #define _PROTOTYPE(function, params)    function()
```

which means

```
00483   _PROTOTYPE( void _exit, (int _status)    );
```

becomes under ANSI:

```
void _exit(int _status);
```

and under K&R:

```
void _exit();
```

Answer (score 3):

The source code you linked to explains it:

> 00009  * If _ANSI ends up being defined, a macro
>   00010  *
>   00011  *      _PROTOTYPE(function, params)
>   00012  *
>   00013  * is defined.  This macro expands in different ways, generating either
>   00014  * ANSI Standard C prototypes or old-style K&R (Kernighan & Ritchie)
>   00015  * prototypes, as needed.  Finally, some programs use _CONST, _VOIDSTAR etc
>   00016  * in such a way that they are portable over both ANSI and K&R compilers.
>   00017  * The appropriate macros are defined here.

Old-style K&R prototypes have the argument *names* first, then the types:

```
int foobar (x, y)
    int x;
    float *y;
{
    /* code */
}
```

ANSI standard prototypes combine them both at the beginning:

```
int foobar (int x, float *y) {
    /* code */
}
```

The `_PROTOTYPE` macro creates an appropriate signature of either type depending on whether or not `_ANSI` is defined. In this specific case, K&R signatures are used for function implementations, but the function declarations either include or omit their arguments depending on whether `_ANSI` is defined.

It is worth noting that K&R-style declarations date from 1978 and most C code currently available will use modern ANSI style signatures. It is rare that you need to support both.

Comment: While what you show is corrent for function definition, the macro is for function declaration, where in K&R you don't note the number of parameters at all.

Answer (score 1):

To accommodate both K&R and ANSI C function declaration styles. Take a look at [Wikipedia article about C evolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)).