# Spec GCC Code; int main PARAMS ((int argc, char **argv)); return function_name define_as_parameter

Tags: c, gcc

recently while I am running some of clang implementation over gcc spec benchmark, I have found that following in gcc spec source code:

```
int main PARAMS ((int argc, char **argv));
```

Any guess what actually means from c programming perspective? What could be the reason to use this?

Comment: By itself, it is not valid C, and therefore it does not mean anything.  In all likelihood, however, the code from which that is drawn defines `PARAMS` as a macro.  In that case, what it means depends on that definition.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607853/why-prototype-is-used-header-files

Comment: I don't see the reason for downvoting, it's something that can easily confuse a beginner programmer. See [ansidecl.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/go-vgo/Mingw/master/include/ansidecl.h), search for `PARAMS` to see the reasoning and the definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why \_PROTOTYPE is used header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607853/why-prototype-is-used-header-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's for compatibility with ancient compilers that didn't support function prototypes.

Modern compilers accept:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv);
```

Ancient ones need:

```
int main ();
```

So to support both with a preprocessor that might not have variadic arguments yet, you can do:

```
#if __STDC__ 
/*all standard compliant compilers since the 1st version of the standard 
  must both define __STDC__ to a truthy value and support function prototypes*/
#    define PARAMS(X) X
#else
#    define PARAMS(X) ()
#endif
/*...*/
int main PARAMS ((int argc, char **argv));
```

Comment: One rule of thumb is, whenever you see double parentheses, it's an indicator that the macro will use the entire inner parenthesis as a "single parameter", so it's often used to provide support for compilers which don't support variadic arguments.

Comment: I understand it now, from my knowledge there could not be anything in between function name and parameters and that's why I get confused. It actually maintains that syntax, but the parameter here is this whole part: PARAMS ((int argc, char **argv)) which is actually a define.